# Find overlapping ranges between different files

Tags: bash, unix, range

I have two files each with a column forming ranges.

File 1

> 23241-24234
>   10023-12300
>   75432-82324

File 2

> 16722-17234
>   92000-94532
>   23600-25000

I am looking for ranges that overlap with a certain % (e.g. 50%) between the two files

In the previous example only the following will be printed (50% overlap):

> 23241-24234 23600-25000

I can do this using Python, but was wondering if there is a quicker bash command that would do the same thing.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by 'bash command'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: And show us what you tried with python, even if it's broken

Comment: the task you want is very specific, in python you will need several lines to make a comparison. So you are sure there is no magic command that do what you want. Python is quicker than bash script , so you can go on with a python script.

Comment: `quicker bash command` definitely not, bash sucks for pretty much anything other than running other commands

Answer (score 1):

In Python, I would write something like this:

```
f1='''\
23241-24234
10023-12300
75432-82324'''

f2='''\
16722-17234
92000-94532
23600-25000'''

f1ranges=[tuple(map(int, l.split('-'))) for l in f1.splitlines()]

for l in f2.splitlines():
    b,e=map(int, l.split('-'))
    s2=set(range(b,e))
    for r in f1ranges:
        s1=set(range(*r))
        if len(s1 & s2)>len(s1)/2:
            print r,(b,e)
```

Prints:

```
(23241, 24234) (23600, 25000)
```

It is hard to beat that with Bash utilities, but `awk` would be the only one to use.

The method I used in Python uses the shortcut of the intersection of a set to determine the length of the overlapping interval. You would need to replicate that set-type functionality or use arithmetic comparisons.

Here is an `awk` framework:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { f1[$0]; next } 
             {
             split($0,a,"-")
             for (e in f1) {
                split(e,b,"-")
                # add your range comparison logic here...
                print a[1],a[2],"   ",b[1],b[2], a[2]-b[1], b[2]-a[1]
                }
             }   ' f1 f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a "fake" bed format and use `bedtools intersect`; https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html

```
$ cat 1.bed
chr1    23241   24234
chr1    10023   12300
chr1    75432   82324

$ cat 2.bed
chr1    16722   17234
chr1    92000   94532
chr1    23600   25000

# sort both files

$ sort -k 1,1 -k2,2n 1.bed > 1.sort.bed
$ sort -k 1,1 -k2,2n 2.bed > 2.sort.bed

$ bedtools intersect -wa -wb -f 0.5 -a 1.sort.bed -b 2.sort.bed
chr1    23241   24234   chr1    23600   25000
```

you can parse the output and strip out the `chr1` labels afterwards

obviously, `bedtools` is not a builtin bash program, but as you can see from the docs for the tools it has a huge amount of options that will likely be useful for you as soon as your needs become more complicated